# Fastest way to fill database with random generated stuff

Tags: python, sqlite

I started learning python first time today while playing around with SQL. I made this undoubtedly very innovative way to fill database with one million random generated entries.

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
db.isolation_level = None

import random
import string

def get_random_string(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    return result_str

i = 0
while i < 1000000:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO RandomBase (name, number) VALUES (?, ?)", [get_random_string(8), random.randint(1900,2000)])
    i += 1
```

But to be honest it is not very fast. What basic ways I can implement to make it go faster? And why is this method exactly so slow? I was thinking about the transaction stuff, but the problem is that any of the begin/commit commands don't seem to work neither I can't turn off the auto commit.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using `executemany()` to do a bulk insert of some larger number of records.  This would avoid making a round trip to and from the SQLite database for each record inserted.  Consider:

```py
def get_random_string(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    return result_str

i = 0
vals = []
sql = "INSERT INTO RandomBase (name, number) VALUES (?, ?)"
while i < 1000000:
    vals.append((get_random_string(8), random.randint(1900,2000)))
    i += 1
    if i % 100 == 0:
        db.executemany(sql, vals)
        vals.clear()
```